# Windows batch file - GOTO command is ignored

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

Here it goes stupid question but please help or my brain will explode! ;)) Some stupid thing which I don't understand...

In short: why after I choose number 7 (exit) the ERRORLEVEL returned is correct but GOTO specified label is ignored and instead it goes to allTasksReboot label...

This is my "code"...

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=150 lines=65
@echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo INSTALLATION MENU
@echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo [ 1 ].All tasks - Unattended with reboot on finish
@echo [ 2 ].All tasks - Unattended without reboot on finish
@echo [ 3 ].All tasks except Software group - Unattended with reboot on finish
@echo [ 4 ].All tasks except Software group - Unattended without reboot on finish
@echo [ 5 ].All tasks except Java 7 installation - Unattended without reboot on finish
@echo [ 6 ].Install only VNC - Unattended
@echo [ 7 ].Exit
@echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHOICE /C:1234567 /N /M "Choose number for installation type."
@echo You press: %ERRORLEVEL%
@pause
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO allTasksReboot
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO allTasks
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO allExceptSoftwareReboot
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO allExceptSoftware
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 GOTO allTasksExceptJava
IF ERRORLEVEL 6 GOTO onlyVnc
IF ERRORLEVEL 7 GOTO scriptend

:allTasksReboot
@echo **************************************************************************
@echo All tasks - Unattended with reboot on finish
@echo **************************************************************************
@pause
goto scriptend

:scriptend
@echo Lets exit...
@pause

:goexit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `IF ERRORLEVEL N command` test if the current ERRORLEVEL value is GREATER THAN OR EQUAL to the given number, so this command must always be executed in descending errorlevels order. You may change your `IF` commands this way:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO allTasksReboot
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 GOTO allTasks
.....
```

Or you may simplify your code a lot if you change your labels to a rigid-format ones and use a direct GOTO command:

```
CHOICE /C:1234567 /N /M "Choose number for installation type."
@echo You press: %ERRORLEVEL%
@pause
GOTO LABEL-%ERRORLEVEL%

:LABEL-1  allTasksReboot
@echo **************************************************************************
@echo All tasks - Unattended with reboot on finish
@echo **************************************************************************
@pause
goto scriptend

:LABEL-7  scriptend
@echo Lets exit...
@pause

:goexit
```

Comment: I choose your answer because of your explanation why this "error" happens. Also thank you for code trick example with label-%errorlevel% :)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 7 GOTO scriptend
IF ERRORLEVEL 6 GOTO onlyVnc
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 GOTO allTasksExceptJava
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO allExceptSoftware
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO allExceptSoftwareReboot
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO allTasks
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO allTasksReboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I probably like using a single GOTO with `LABEL-<n>` names best, but @Endoro's solution is the correct way to use `IF ERRORLEVEL`.
If you didn't want to have to order the IF checks, you can also use the value of `%ERRORLEVEL%`:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 7 GOTO scriptend
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 5 GOTO allTasksExceptJava
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 GOTO allTasks
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 6 GOTO onlyVnc
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO allTasksReboot
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 3 GOTO allExceptSoftwareReboot
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 4 GOTO allExceptSoftware
```